# How to save files on a cron in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Right now I have a function on a class that when ran makes a curl call, downloads a file, and moves/renames the file, then saves a record of the file path in the database.

This works fine if I call `$class->importImages()` in a controller, saves the images and everything. So now I throw it in a cron in a loop that says if the classes images_imported column = 0, import it's images.

I can see it's running, as the database is slowly filling with entries, but it doesn't appear to be making the file anywhere when ran via a cron.

Here's the main part of the code that works fine when ran via a controller...

```
$directory_path = 'images/' . $this->id . '/';

if (!file_exists($directory_path)) {
   mkdir($directory_path, 0777, true);
}

$image_path = $directory_path . $filename . '.png';

$fp = fopen($image_path, 'w+');

fwrite($fp, $image);
fclose($fp);

$im = new \Imagick($image_path);
$im->setImageFormat("png");
$im->writeImage($image_path);

Drawing::firstOrCreate([
                         'parent_id' => $this->id,
                         'path'      => $image_path
                       ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The path is different when fired in the Kernel.php for the cron. Changing the path line to this fixed it and it now worked in both places:

```
$directory_path = app()->basePath() . 'images/' . $this->id . '/';
```